# MySQL Debezium Kafka : schema isn't known to this connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I started the MySQL Debezium Kafka Connector(**Version: 0.9.2.Final**) with one table in the **"table.whitelist"** and It was working fine. While adding another table in the whitelist and restarts the connector, I am getting the below error.

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Encountered change event for table paperclip.iltwhose schema isn't known to this connector
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:230)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:208)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:477)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.notifyEventListeners(BinaryLogClient.java:1095)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:943)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:580)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:825)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Encountered change event for table paperclip.iltwhose schema isn't known to this connector
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.informAboutUnknownTableIfRequired(BinlogReader.java:727)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleUpdateTableMetadata(BinlogReader.java:702)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:461)
    ... 5 more
```

Please find the below configuration I have used. I hope with this setting(**"database.history.store.only.monitored.tables.ddl": "false"**), it should work.

How can I resolve the case?

```
{
    "name": "Mysql-rnd-engagex",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "database.hostname": "devmysql.xxxx.net",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "xxxxxx",
    "database.password": "xxxxx",
    "database.server.name": "rnd_engagex_cdc",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "xxxxxx.aivencloud.com:xxxx",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "rnd_engagex_dbhistory",
    "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "false",
    "database.history.store.only.monitored.tables.ddl": "false",
    "include.schema.changes": "false",
    "include.query": "false",
    "table.ignore.builtin": "true",
    "database.whitelist": "paperclip",
    "table.whitelist": "paperclip.elearning",    //added new table : "paperclip.elearning,paperclip.ilt"
    "column.blacklist": "paperclip.elearning.description",
    "gtid.source.filter.dml.events": "true",
    "tombstones.on.delete": "true",
    "connect.keep.alive": "true",
    "snapshot.minimal.locks": "true",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.location": "/xxxx/yyyy/keys/public.truststore.jks",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "database.history.consumer.ssl.truststore.location": "/xxxx/yyyy/keys/public.truststore.jks",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.password": "password",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.keystore.location": "/xxxx/yyyy/keys/public.keystore.p12",
    "database.history.consumer.ssl.truststore.password": "password",
    "database.history.consumer.ssl.keystore.location": "/xxxx/yyyy/keys/public.keystore.p12",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.keystore.type": "PKCS12",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.keystore.password": "ppppppppp",
    "database.history.consumer.ssl.key.password": "ppppppppp",
    "database.history.producer.security.protocol": "SSL",
    "database.history.consumer.ssl.keystore.type": "PKCS12",
    "database.history.consumer.ssl.keystore.password": "ppppppppp",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.key.password": "ppppppppp",
    "database.history.consumer.security.protocol": "SSL",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add property "snapshot.new.tables":"parallel" while creating connector, then only you will be able to whitelist more tables at later stage. This is not given in documentation, since the feature came as beta in 0.9.x

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this will work if we create a new connector. How to fix it with the running connector? I got response from MySQL-Debezium community "_This issue has been taken care of in **version 0.10.0.Final**_"

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-175 was added in 0.9.0. you can cross check on https://debezium.io/releases/0.9/release-notes/. But with older versions there might be some issues. Even on 0.10.0 Amazon RDS MySQL don't work, but other deployments works where full lock is accessible.

Comment: As you suggested I created a new Connector with this "snapshot.new.tables":"parallel" configuration. I started with one table in the table.whitelist and warked perfectly. Then  I added another table, that related DDL statements are updated in the DBHistory topic. But I am getting this error ```org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Table 'elearning_lab' was not locked with LOCK TABLES Error code: 1100; SQLSTATE: HY000.
 at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:230)
 ```

Comment: Which debezium version you are using? Also, are you using any managed service like AWS RDS for MySQL?

Comment: Version mentioned in the question. Version: 0.9.2.Final. Yes AWS  RDS for MySQL

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, AWS RDS is not supported/working with parallel snapshotting. Associated ticket - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-1524